# CASify JBoss Applications

Tags: java, authentication, jboss, cas, single-sign-on

Is there any Tutorial or Example on how to integrate CAS into JBoss (for EJB and WebClient Authentication) without using JBoss Portal ?

Comment: I'm also looking for the same information. Any one please.